# the right person vs a right person

Tags: articles

"We need to look for the right person for this job."

The person saying it can't point, either in his imagination or physically, to such a person, so the reference is indefinite. And it is specific insofar as it needs to be a right person.

Question: Does substituting the "the" for an "a" maintain the same meaning? What's your take on all of this?

P.S. I think that the definite article here is more idiomatic and common

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Idiomatically, we nearly always use the *definite* article before ***right** person [for the job]* - the implication being *there's **one particular** person we're looking for* (even if we've no idea yet who that person is).

It's syntactically the same as looking for ***the best*** person for the job, That's as opposed to saying we need ***a suitable** person to do the job* - where there might potentially be many suitable people (and we don't care which *specific* one we get).

---

It's not easy to answer OP''s question *What would it **mean** if the indefinite article was used?,* because by far the most likely "meaning" would simply be that it came from a non-native speaker.

If a *native* speaker referred to ***a** right person*, I might just  ask them what they meant. There's no "default" meaning to the non-idiomatic form<sup>1</sup>, but obviously a native speaker would be trying to convey *something* by his unusual phrasing.

---

<sup>1</sup> See @Douglas's comment below. If *heavy stress* was placed on the indefinite article, very likely speaker would be making the point that there are *multiple* "right" applicants. But even if not intended humorously, such an utterance would effectively be "wordplay" - whose net effect forces ***right*** to be understood as *[any] **suitable*** rather than *[the] **best***.

Comment: As a native speaker myself, I would expect that a native speaker referring to "**a** right person" a) would intentionally emphasize the indefinite article, and b) would intend to convey an explicit acknowledgement that there are multiple people who are equally right.

Comment: ***If*** heavy stress was placed on the indefinite article, it seems very possible the speaker would indeed be trying to make that point. But it's both a strange thing to say, and a strange way of saying it. Why not just say *We need **a suitable** person to do the job* - same as everyone else who might want to make such a trite observation?

Comment: In this case I think it would be more natural to say "one of the right persons" rather than "a right person"